# Positioning and Resizing Captions in Final Cut

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, subtitles, closed-captioning

I have a video for which I need to include captions. The video itself has burned-in captions. I would like to include the new captions on top of the old ones. However, when I import captions, the standard Final Cut position is lower than where I need them. In addition, their font size is way smaller than that of the original.

Question: if I have captions as .ASS file (Aegis sub) and am able to export them as .SRT, how can adjust them to my taste in Final Cut?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an article in the FCP user guide.
All you need should be explained here.
[Format caption text in Final Cut Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/final-cut-pro/ver23b2d99f0/mac)